# UTC conversions over two days with datetime.now()

Tags: python, utc

My script attempts to determine if the current time is between these two time fields: `execute_before` and `execute_after`.

A simple `execute_after <= datetime.now() <= execute_before` works for the general case, e.g.

```
execute_after = '08:00:00'
execute_before = '18:00:00'
```

But the case where the time span between execute_after and execute_before *span over 2 different days* causes an issue, and I can't seem to figure out a way around it.

**Problem:**

```
execute_after = '19:00:00'
execute_before = '05:00:00'
```

**Expected output:**

```
Time difference: '10:00:00'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, well... times without dates do that. What type values are `execute_after` and `execute_before`? How are you retrieving them from the database? Are you using `datetime` objects? Strings? Please read [ask]. Ideally, we'd like to see a [mre].

Comment: if it is cross day,maybe you need change the column type from time to datetime

Comment: Are you looking for [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?  `(18 - 8) % 24 == 10`, and `(5 - 19) % 24 == 10`. I can put a full answer together if this is on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

```
if execute_before < execute_after
    execute_before = execute_before + 24:00:00

difference = execute_before - execute_after
```